# Single plus operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

Just saw this in underscore's source:

```
if (obj.length === +obj.length) {
    ...
}
```

What does the `plus` do? I never saw this before.

Is it considered a good practice among developers?

Comment: @epascarello The point of this question is also if the named technique is considered a good practice among developers, which is not discused on the other question

Comment: Good Practice is a "I think blue is best color" type of thing. One guy will say, no, use Number(), other guy will say use +. And the selected answer here does not say it. ;)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The plus converts a string to a float. The code you provided is equivalent to the following:

```
if ( obj.length === Number(obj.length) ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It's also equivalent to `if(typeof obj.length === "number")`, which would be better as it's much less confusing.

Comment: `if(var === !!var)` same trick with booleans

Comment: Is this considered a good practice?

Comment: @jviotti - I think so. I use it all the time.

Comment: This is equivalent to `Number(...)`, not `parseFloat(...)`, as easily shown by the input case "0xf".